# textbox display formatting with decimal point

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I want to add "," after every group of 3 digits. Eg : when I type 123456789 the textbox will display 123,456,789 and I got it with this code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        decimal valueBefore = decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
        textBox1.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N0}", valueBefore);
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
}
```

I want to be more specific for this format. I want to type numeric only for this textbox and use decimal format (type . after that) like `123,456,789.00` and I try to use this code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: how does it not work? What does the code here actually do? If there is an error please include it, if there is faulty output please include it

Comment: I want to join both of them..but I don't know how I do it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use digit grouping format string as defined in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
Something like following should work (modified version):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal myValue;
    if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out myValue))
    {
        textBox1.Text = myValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
        textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }           
}
```

Comment: This needs work.  TryParse also needs to know about the culture.  KeyPress doesn't make much sense when you can paste text with Ctrl+V.  Use the Validating event instead.

Comment: the result so weird dude..
that is cool when text box is changed, there is auto decimal..but when I type 12345, the textbox display 54,321.00

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx#Y600

After you have parsed the value into the decimal data type, just assign `textbox1.Text` the value of that decimal variable using `ToString`, and passing it a format parameter.

```
TextBox1.Text = valueBefore.ToString("C")
```

As far as preventing the input to the textbox, I thought for sure there was a mode for that already.

Anyway, try this:

```
if !(Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == Keys.Decimal && !(TextBox1.Text.Contains("."))))
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```